# How can i learn which js file is started with node command

Tags: node.js, windows, filenames, pid

I am using nodejs in my development. Our company IT person wanted windows OS. They installed everything needed and we upload the applications. They could not use PM2 for separate app management. Now we have 2 different file running on same machine. One is server.js which consists both frontend and backend js app. Second one is loadroutefees.js which is actually batch-like process with crontab. Now they want to understand which PID belongs to which app. I've searched internet. But nothing useful was there. We're stuck now. Are there any answer to these? How we can know which process uses which js files?

Comment: If GUI app is appropriate, you can try [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer): it provides info about command line used to start the process.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 'tasklist' command in windows, I hope this should help [check this](https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix)

Comment: tasklist is not giving what i want. I want to see the running jobname in nodejs, as i see like in pm2 list.